# Is there any open-source alternative to IBM MQ MFT/WMQFTE?

Tags: open-source, ibm-mq, file-transfer, mq, websphere-mq-fte

We use IBM MQ MFT (MQFTE) to provide secure, guaranteed file transfer in our distributed network. But IBM MQ MFT is quite expensive one.

So, is there any comparable open-source enterprise solution to consider instead IBM MQ MFT(MQFTE)?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't Google return [Universal File Mover](http://www.capitalware.com/ufm_overview.html) in the search list?